# Can I use HootSuite API for my ASP.NET web application for creating dashboard?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, hootsuite

I want to create my ASP.NET dashboard, and want to display charts from Google Analytics account by using hootsuite API.

I have created an account on hootsuite.com, fetched my necessary data from my GA account, and created sample charts in hootsuite account only.  Now I want to display these charts in my website.

I am totally new to this API and have no idea what can I achieve through this API.  Can any one help me understand what the API is capable of?

Comment: Thanks for your tagging @Johm Conde

Comment: @JohnConde shouldn't the tag be "hootsuite" ( http://hootsuite.com/ ) ?

Comment: I doesn't know much about hootsuite but i think you can fetch data from your analytic account by just only google analytic api .
First you can use there query explorer to fetch your required data http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: @Kamran Shahid : i know that,actually right now i am using that way only to fetch data but now requirement changed and i have to use hootsuite. any way thanks for reply.